# Erro visual no WebView

Tags: android, webview

To utilizando um   webview para expor meu site, porém nas laterais ele fica com duas barra brancas como na foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.meudominio.com/");

    WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); //5mb
    ws.setSupportZoom(false);
    ws.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    ws.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    ws.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    ws.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver pessoal, so adicionar como verdadeiro o wideviewport:

```
 WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
        ws.setUseWideViewPort(true);`
```